# Replication compatibility between minor MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a dedicated server running MySQL 5.7, installed using MySQL's Yum repository.

Yum always installs the latest version, which is MySQL 5.7.11 at the time of this writing.

I want to replicate this server to Amazon RDS, to have an offsite, real-time backup.

The problem is, RDS is always at least one minor version behind. To illustrate this, they just released MySQL 5.7 on RDS yesterday, yet they did not pick the latest version, and only offer MySQL 5.7.10.

So I would be replicating from a newer master to an older slave.

**Is this acceptable, as long as we're talking minor versions?**

The only page I could find on the MySQL website is this one:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-compatibility.html

It basically says that you can only replicate from an older master to a newer slave, but they are talking major releases, i.e. 5.6 to 5.7.

This does not give me a clue to whether it is OK to replicate to a slave running an older *minor* version, e.g. from a 5.6.11 master to a 5.6.10 slave.

Comment: Get the .rpm for 5.7.10 and install that! Or else test the bejesus out of your proposed setup! From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html) the manual is self-contadictory - check first idea.

Comment: That may be the wisest choice I'm afraid.

Comment: I can make it an answer! :-)

Comment: You can indeed :-) I will wait however to see if someone has more insight / experience on whether this can be a problem or not, before accepting an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Get the .rpm for 5.7.10 and install that! Or else test the bejesus out of your proposed setup! From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html): the manual is self-contradictory:

```
Sentence 1:
```

> MySQL supports replication from one release series to the next higher
>   release series. For example, you can replicate from a master running
>   MySQL 5.5 to a slave running MySQL 5.6, from a master running MySQL
>   5.6 to a slave running MySQL 5.7, and so on.

```
Sentence 2: (this **is** the biggie)
```

> However, you may encounter difficulties when replicating from an older
>   master to a newer slave if the master uses statements or relies on
>   behavior no longer supported in the version of MySQL used on the
>   slave.

```
Sentence 3:
```

> The use of more than two MySQL Server versions is not supported in
>   replication setups involving multiple masters, regardless of the
>   number of master or slave MySQL servers. This restriction applies not
>   only to release series, but to version numbers within the same release
>   series as well. For example, if you are using a chained or circular
>   replication setup, you cannot use MySQL 5.7.1, MySQL 5.7.2, and MySQL
>   5.7.4 concurrently, although you could use any two of these releases together.

Check out my first idea - I firmly believe that it's (by far) your best option - no compatibility worries (that's the great thing about Open Source software).

Comment: About point 2, I understand it as being only when using long-deprecated features, that would have been removed in the next major version. This is quite normal. It doesn't apply to me anyway, as it only affects major versions. About point 3, it seems to only apply to multiple masters running 3 different versions of MySQL, so I shouldn't be affected. That said, I get the point, I'm probably better off with the exact same same version of MySQL to not dare the devil.